Why do engines with cylinder offset not suffer from increased frictional losses on the compression and exhaust strokes?
I recently watched the D4A YouTube video on cylinder offset, and for the most part it makes sense. Longer power and intake strokes, lower frictional losses on the power and intake strokes, greater leverage, etc. However, I was left with the question of why the compression and exhaust strokes do not suffer from increased frictional losses. My intuition tells me that what the design loses in friction from the power and intake strokes would be more than made back during the compression and exhaust strokes. Given, in the D4A video, the offset was greatly exaggerated, but I still cant figure it out. I have spent the past day trying to do the math, and (assuming my math is correct) made it to the integral of friction over 720 degrees of crankshaft rotation on the non-offset piston for something resembling total work done. Unfortunately for me, the trig when dealing with the offset piston is beyond my ability. Am I even approaching this problem correctly? Is there some simple explanation I cant figure out?

what leads you to believe that they don't?

The increased angle of the connecting rod pushing the piston into the cylinder wall is why I don't believe they do.  In my head, losing a couple of degrees on the intake and combustion strokes would only alleviate a small amount of friction compared to what would be added by gaining a couple of degrees on the compression and exhaust strokes.
